# Symfony2 tries to log to DB on other user than specified in parameters.yml

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to move app to server and I get this error and don't know how to deal with it.

```
[2015-02-19 18:32:28] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception PDOException: "SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" at /home/dmad/domains/dmad.test2.itme.eu/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php line 40 {"exception":"[object] (PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at /home/dmad/domains/dmad.test2.itme.eu/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:40)"} []
```

My parameteres.yml looks like this:

```
parameters:
   database_driver: pdo_mysql
   database_host: localhost
   database_port: null
   database_name: test
   database_user: test
   database_password: password
```

I cleared cache with --env=prod and tried every other solution I found and nothing fixed this. I don't have access to console. I can login to PhpMyAdmin with no problem. It seems to me that symfony doesn't read this parameters.yml file. Someone knows what might be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the database details also in your config file(s).
Since you changed to production mode, check your config_prod.yml 
there is probably something like

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    ...
        host:     "localhost"
        port:     3306
        dbname:   "dbase"
        user:     "myuser"
        password: "passwd"
```

To use the settings from your parameters file, change it to

```
driver:   "%database_driver%"
host:     "%database_host%"
port:     "%database_port%"
dbname:   "%database_name%"
user:     "%database_user%"
password: "%database_password%"
```

(or enter the details directly in the config or config_prod file)

Comment: I have standard setup. Config_prod.yml imports config.yml which imports parameters.yml and has those values with %%. Tried to hardcode connection details into config_prod.yml and then in config.yml still the same error.

Comment: Check the user/group and rights of these files (and folder).

Comment: All folder has 755 and all the files has 644 permission. I dont have acces to server and don't know how to check user/group otherwise.

Comment: It can come from the fact that the app/cache folder is owned by an user but you are running the clear:cache command from another user. Is it a shared hosting or do you just not have access to it ? Because shared hosting solutions rarely play well with symfony2.

Comment: This for an job interview. They gave me  login/pass for ftp and mysql and ask me to deploy the app. It's theirs shared hosting I guess. I wrote them an email explaining that the ownership might be the problem. Thanks for answers guys!